# Creating constraint based on a value from referenced table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

**Pencils:**

```
ID(PK): 0,1,2,3

Pencil: Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4

Color_ID(FK, references Colors(ID)): 0,0,0,0
```

**Colors:**

```
ID(PK):0,1,2

Color:Red, Blue, Green

Availability:Yes, No, No
```

I want to create constraint in the Pencil table so that the user cannot enter the Color_ID value of a color whose availability is No. What's the best way to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: What should happen if the availability of a color changes from "yes" to "no"? Should this be allowed with existing rows remaining valid? If so, you can't use a constraint for this, but must use a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [superkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superkey) to the color table that includes the availability information, and then use a foreign key with a computed column to ensure that it's constrained:

```
create table Colors (
    ID int not null,
    Name varchar(30) not null,
    Available bit not null,
    constraint PK_Colors PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    constraint UQ_Color_Names UNIQUE (Name),
    constraint UQ_Color_AvailabilityXRef UNIQUE (ID,Available)
)
go
create table Pencils (
    ID int not null,
    Pencil varchar(20) not null,
    ColorID int not null,
    _Available as CAST(1 as bit) persisted,
    constraint PK_Pencils PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    constraint FK_Pencil_Colors FOREIGN KEY (ColorID) references Colors (ID),
    constraint FK_PenciL_Color_AvailabilityXRef FOREIGN KEY (ColorID,_Available) 
                                                      references Colors (ID,Available)
)
```

You'll note that strictly speaking, `FK_Pencil_Colors` is now redundant. I prefer to retain it since it's the "real" FK but others may choose to drop it.

Note also that this prevents a color from being made unavailable whilst there are still pencils referencing it, an added constraint bonus here.<sup>1</sup>

Finally, it's just my convention that I prefix names with `_` when they're not intended to be used by "other people". They're there to help me build the DRI.

---

<sup>1</sup>As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) comments, this may not actually be your desired behaviour. Bear in mind that generally, constraints state "eternal truths". If it's a constraint, then it should be possible to delete and re-insert your data without violating constraints. If you have a *temporal* requirement, such as "X and Y should be true *at the point in time at which the row is inserted*" then it's usually best to deal with this using triggers.